# unable to create a new user in firebase using android studio

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I don't have any errors and i have copied the code from the documentation and other tutorials but i am not sure why the registration is failing. everything works till i hit the button and it just shows that the registration failed,

1. I placed my permissions in the manifest file
2. I enabled the email/password authentication in the firebase console
3. I registerd it exactly how it is supposed to be done

I wanted to register and check the users in the firebase console

```
package com.example.auth;

import static androidx.constraintlayout.widget.StateSet.TAG;

import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText email,password,confirmpasswordreg;
Button register;
TextView alreadylogin;
FirebaseAuth mauth;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        email=findViewById(R.id.editTextTextEmailAddressreg);
        password=findViewById(R.id.passwordregister);
        alreadylogin=findViewById(R.id.textView4reg);
        register=findViewById(R.id.buttonreg);
        confirmpasswordreg=findViewById(R.id.cnfmpassreg);
        mauth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();                             


        register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String username=email.getText().toString();
                String passwords=password.getText().toString();
                String confirmpassword=confirmpasswordreg.getText().toString();

                    mauth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(username,passwords)
                            .addOnCompleteListener(MainActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                                        Log.d(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:success");
                                        FirebaseUser user = mauth.getCurrentUser();
                                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "sign up success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    } else {
                                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                                        Log.w(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "sign up failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                    }
                                
                            });
                }
            }
        });


    }
}
```

I just wanted to the emails and the passwords on firebase

Comment: what error are you getting when failed ?

Comment: Thank you, for your reply, I forgot to check my log to see whats the actual issue that's taking place. I was only entering 3 characters for my password where the min requirement is 6. @WahdatJan

Comment: @Dev007 Yes, It just clicked for me, I got then problem, thanks for your reply :), I was only giving in 3 characters for my password where as the min requirement was 6.

Comment: is it working now ?

Comment: @WahdatJan It is :)